# How to display glyph inside button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

In a form I have the following submit button:

```
<%= f.submit "Send message".html_safe, class: "buttony" %>
```

I'm using `font-awesome` throughout my app without problems, however if I try to add a glyph inside the button with the code below, the `<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>` code is shown as text and the glyph is not displayed.

What am I doing wrong? Has it perhaps got to do with two classes in one line?

```
<%= f.submit "<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> Send message".html_safe, class: "buttony" %>
```

**Update**: Removing `html.safe` from the code makes no difference. The source code of the page in the browser is:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> Send message" class="buttony" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it with a regular HTML button:

```
<button class="buttony" type="submit">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  Send message
</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to do the trick. I was wondering though if this isn't a problem. Because why would we otherwise normally use Ruby `f.submit`? How does it know that it's "f" that it needs to submit?

Comment: @Marty If a button or a submit input is inside a form, the form will be submitted when they are clicked. It's just regular HTML, Ruby's only function here is generating HTML. That said, the last time I checked, `f.button` or `f.submit` needed so many hacks for the above that regular HTML is just simpler for custom buttons. OTOH a non-button `f.input` has many other functions like generating a label and an error indicator, setting appropriate classes, wrapping them all etc., which aren't relevant for a button. A side note: `<button>` is much more CSS-customizable than `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

On following [Halil Özgür Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34481038/3098330) You could re-write as

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "buttony", value: 'Send message') do %>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
<% end %>
```